# ajax data variable issues

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm having trouble trying to combine two variables to populate the "data:" field of my .ajax request.

When I use alert() to write out the variables, everything looks good. But somehow the data is not being formed correctly.

Here is my code:

```
            var itemName = $(this).closest("tr").data("str");
            var itemValue = $(this).closest("tr").data("dataitem");

            var dataObj = {};
            dataObj[itemName] = itemValue;

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                dataType: "json",
                data: dataObj,
             ...
```

Thanks

Comment: That would result in a parameter with the name from the variable `itemName` being sent with a value from the variable `itemValue`. Note that `dataType` has nothing to do with the data you send the server (it's very poorly named), it has to do with what you expect back. Normally you want to send the data to the server URI-encoded, which `ajax` will do for you automatically with your code as presented. What makes you think the data isn't being sent right (unless you're expecting to get JSON, in which case, my previous comment is why you're not).

Comment: are you looking for a json request body?

Comment: @999cm999 and if you are - why?  For simple data there's normally no good reason not to use `x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: -1 for ambiguous question and not coming back to clarify!

Comment: it's only been like 15 minutes since I first posted...sorry

Comment: I'm not having issues with JSON, if I hard code in the data element like "data: {name:value}, then it works fine.

Comment: so what's the problem then?

Comment: I don't think I'm formatting it correctly by doing it like this: dataObj[itemName] = itemValue; I also tried this: "data: {itemName:itemValue} but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using object literal notation.

```
var dataObj = {
    name: itemName,
    value: itemValue
}
```

Comment: no, it will not send the data as JSON, they'll still be URI encoded.  Apart from that this is correct.

Comment: downvote because i misworded my answer? seems harsh since it's the right answer

Comment: @iAmClownShoe: No, downvote because the answer is almost certainly wrong (as alnitak pointed out). There's nothing wrong with how the OP is sending the data. They're giving `ajax` an object, you're giving `ajax` an object. All you did was turn it into two parameters with different names, and almost certainly in a way that isn't what the OP wants.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you sure?  It seems to me more likely that the OP wants `name=_itemName_&value=_itemValue_` than `_itemName_=_itemValue_`

Comment: yeah that's what i thought too

Comment: Not to me. Gosh, wouldn't it be nice if the OP bothered to tell us? ;-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it would certainly help, but I do think that downvote is a _bit_ on the harsh side.

Comment: it seeems to me that OP actually wants his key to be set to whatever the value of itemName is with it's value set as the value of itemValue. but it's tough to tell because his code confuses me

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Reason I thought that the way he was formatting the data incorrectly was because of this, " But somehow the data is not being formed correctly." -OP

Comment: @iAmClownShoe that's what the OP's _current_ code does.  Perhaps he's just expecting to receive JSON instead of form-encoded data?

Comment: Sorry...I need the data to be JSON.  I'm trying to get the format of the data: element(dataObj) to be {itemName: itemValue}